# Conditional select from other tables based on a field in first table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with sales data and a field defining the type of item sold where item_sold can have two values: 'i' and 'u'

**Table sales**

```
sale_no  item_type   item_id
123         i         111
124         i         945
125         u         345
126         u         777
......
```

The description of the items is in two other tables...this is necessary...the item information cannot be in the same table for different item types due to other fields not shown below....

**Table item_i**

```
item_id    item_description    Other Fields.....
 111         Some random text description
 945         ......
```

**Table item_u**

```
item_id    item_description    Other Fields....
 345         Some random text description
 777         ......
```

What I want to do is this (pseudocode)

```
SELECT sales.*
 IF item_type = i
  Select item_i.* (sales and item_i are joined on item_id)
 ELSE IF item_type = u
  SELECT item_u.* (sales and item_u are joined on item_id)
WHERE sales.sale_no = some_sale_no
```

I have read a few answers which point to the SELECT with CASE statement but I am not able to construct the query.....in a nutshell I am looking for this:

```
SELECT * FROM table A
AND depending on tableA.some_field value
 select * from table B OR select * from table C
where table A.sale_no = 123
```

Final Result is ONE ROW:

```
sale_no   item_type   item_id   item_description    other_fields_from_either_item_i/u
```

Comment: please add your expected output.

Comment: The expected output would be the entire row from the sales table with the corresponding row from EITHER the 'item_u' or the 'item_i' table....since the sale_no field in the table 'sales' is the PK, only ONE ROW will be returned

Comment: Edit your question with the desired result!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you necessarily need to use a `CASE` statement here.  Rather, just join the two item tables to `sales` and then use `COALESCE()` to display the description which is not `NULL`:

```
SELECT s.sale_no,
       s.item_type,
       COALESCE(i1.item_description, i2.item_description, 'No description available')
FROM sales s
LEFT JOIN item_i i1
    ON s.item_id = i1.item_id
LEFT JOIN item_u i2
    ON s.item_id = i2.item_id
WHERE s.sale_no = 123
```

Even in the case where you expect to have more than 2 item tables, `COALESECE` should still get the job done, assuming that you expect only one joined table to have a non `NULL` description.

[Click here](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/coalesce.php) for a good site which discusses how MySQL's `COALESECE()` function works.

**Update:**

I assumed that an item can only have an entry in either `item_i` or `item_u`, but not both.  If it could have an entry in both, then you can try the following `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT s.sale_no,
       s.item_type,
       COALESCE(i1.item_description, 'No item_i description available'),
       COALESCE(i2.item_description, 'No item_u description available')
```

Comment: I am not sure what the 'coalesce' function is doing here...I need to select a row from table B if a field in table A is 'i' or table C if the a field in table A is 'u'

Comment: @user2267462 `COALESCE(a, b)` will choose `a` if it is _not_ `NULL`, otherwise it will choose `b`.  This works well in your scenario, because you want to choose the non `NULL` entry from one of two item tables.

Comment: This is letting me get ONE field from either of the item table...what if I wanted ALL the fields from either of the table? Could I COALESCE (i1.*,i2.*....)??

Comment: nah, it picks the first non-null one. I would bet `*` would never work. Plus it is deliberate how they are ordered. So `*`, being nebulous off the top of your head, wouldn't make any sense